# What is the point of the static valueOf() method? (enumerations)

Tags: java, enumeration, value-of

I am learning about enumerations and I don't understand the purpose this method serves.

Example:

```
enum Fruits{
    apple, pear, orange
}

class Demo{
    f = Fruits.valueOf("apple");  //returns apple... but I had to type it!
                                 // so why wouldn't I save myself some time
                                 // and just write: f = Fruits.apple; !?

}
```

Comment: Maybe you received the String `"apple"` as user input and want to try to resolve it to an enum element?

Comment: One example would be a serialized text message (e.g. JSON) where one value is the representation of an enum element. In order to de-serialize an actual enum element from that, using `valueOf` would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `valueOf` method is to provide you a way of obtaining `Fruits` values presented to your program as `String`s - for example, when values come from a configuration file or a user input:

```
String fruitName = input.next();
Fruits fruit = Fruits.valueOf(fruitName);
```

Above, the name of the fruit is provided by end-user. Your program can read and process it as an `enum`, without knowing which fruit would be supplied at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dasblinkenlight, You can use Enum.valueOf() method If you have some runtime input.

```
String input="apple" //It may be passed from some where
Fruits fruit = Fruits.valueOf(input);  // Here you will get the object of type Fruits
```

One more thing I want to add here, If the enum doesn't exist for this input, then It valueOf() method will throw a Runtime exception, instead of returning null. The exception will be:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
```